# Query different collection by different variable in mongoengine and Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

Is it possible to use variable as the part of collection name and query different collection based on the name in mongoengine?

For example:

There are 3 collections in my mongoDB

- collection_first
- collection_second
- collection_third

and execute a simple for-loop like:

```
collection_names = ['first', 'second', 'third']
for name in collection_names:
    ## Query the collection_+`name` here
```

By the way, I am using mongoengin in Django, how to set the model.py of this kind of scenario?

```
class Testing(DynamicDocument):
    # The collection_name should be dynamic, isn't it?
    meta = {'collection' : 'collection_name'}         
    user_name = StringField(db_field='user_name')
```

Thank you very much.

---

**Update the solution.**

Define the Model in models.py without meta:

```
class Testing(DynamicDocument):
    ## Do NOT use the meta to point to a specific collection.
    user_name = StringField(db_field='user_name')
```

When you call the function, use `switch_collection` to switch to the real collection:

```
def search_in_testing(self, name, **kwargs):
    with switch_collection(Testing, 'colection_%s' % (name)):
        search_results = Testing.objects(**kwargs)
    return search_results
```

In your code, just call the function in for loop:

```
collection_names = ['first', 'second', 'third']
for name in collection_names:
    search_results = search_in_testing(name, name=name)
```

Reference: [switch_collection in mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/connecting.html?#switch-collection)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following test in this **[commit](https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/commit/c62b6321adaba6c3eb54ce2dc2c1bd3069568399)** would be of help in some way:

```
def test_dynamic_collection_naming(self)
      def create_collection_name(cls):
          return "PERSON"

      class DynamicPerson(Document): 
          name = StringField()
          age = IntField()

          meta = {'collection': create_collection_name}

      collection = DynamicPerson._get_collection_name()
      self.assertEquals(collection, 'PERSON') 
      DynamicPerson(name='Test User', age=30).save()  
      self.assertTrue(collection in self.db.collection_names())
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it like this. As an example,

```
for name in collection_names:
    for doc in db[collection_+'name'].find():
        print doc
```

Here db is `Database` object.

Comment: Do you know how to define the `model.py` in django?

Comment: mongoengine still does not support django i guess. I didn't try it. I'll research a bit and let you know.

Comment: Thank you, I am using before 0.90, it support Django in that version.

Comment: HI, I found a way to solve my problem, please see my update if you are interesting.